# mozilla dev tools bug with bootstrap

Tags: firefox, bootstrap-4

I decided to try Bootstrap 4. I have rather a simple HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Template</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1">
                </div>
                <div class="col-10">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I hover the latest *col-1* element in the developer tools, the horizontal scrollbar appears. Look at the image below.
[Firefox bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zshxv.png)

Who have any ideas how to wrastle with it?

Answer (score 0):

your code is okay
I tried it in Google chrome, and the horizontal scrollbar doesn't appear
also I download firefox and installed it, then tried what you made, and there is no horizontal scrollbar as well
You may have an error in your firefox, you may download the new version from here;
https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/

Comment: I have just updated Firefox. I have tried English and local versions. The problem still exists.

Comment: hmm,
then may be your screen resolution? I copied you code with no modifications, and all is okay, try to test in another PC